# Lumia 520: "The device has either stopped responding..."

Tags: 8.1, lumia-520, file-transfer, error

When I try to copy an image (or any file) from my laptop/desktop PC to my Lumia 520, the following message appears: "The device has either stopped responding or has been disconnected".
Until about 2 months ago, it worked perfectly (not only images, but any file formats).
Please, help me, because right now the only thing I can do is email myself the file, and download it in my phone (which is time consuming, inefficient, and impractical).
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried a different USB cable?